# Why does 2>&1 need to come before a | (pipe) but after a "> myfile" (redirect to file)?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdout, pipeline

When combining stderr with stdout, why does `2>&1` need to come before a `|` (pipe) but after a `> myfile` (redirect to file)?

To redirect stderr to stdout for file output:

```
  echo > myfile 2>&1
```

To redirect stderr to stdout for a pipe:

```
  echo 2>&1 | less
```

My assumption was that I could just do:

```
  echo | less 2>&1
```

and it would work, but it doesn't.  Why not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A *pipeline* is a |-delimited list of *commands*. Any redirections you specify apply to the constituent commands (simple or compound), but not to the pipeline as a whole. Each pipe chains one command's stdout to the stdin of the next by implicitly applying a redirect to each subshell *before* any redirects associated with a command are evaluated.

```
cmd 2>&1 | less
```

First stdout of the first subshell is redirected to the pipe from which `less` is reading. Next, the `2>&1` redirect is applied to the first command. Redirecting stderr to stdout works because stdout is already pointing at the pipe.

```
cmd | less 2>&1
```

Here, the redirect applies to `less`. Less's stdout and stderr both presumably started out pointed at the terminal, so `2>&1` in this case has no effect.

If you want a redirect to apply to an entire pipeline, to group multiple commands as part of a pipeline, or to nest pipelines, then use a command group (or any other *compound command*):

```
{ { cmd1 >&3; cmd2; } 2>&1 | cmd3; } 3>&2
```

Might be a typical example. The end result is: `cmd1` and `cmd2`'s stderr -> `cmd3`; `cmd2`'s stdout -> `cmd3`; and `cmd1` and `cmd3`'s stderr, and `cmd3`'s stdout -> the terminal.

If you use the Bash-specific `|&` pipe, things get stranger, because each of the pipeline's stdout redirects still occur first, but the stderr redirect actually comes last. So for example:

```
f() { echo out; echo err >&2; }; f >/dev/null |& cat
```

Now, counterintuitively, all output is hidden. First stdout of `f` goes to the pipe, next stdout of `f` is redirected to `/dev/null`, and finally, stderr is redirected to stdout (`/dev/null` still).

I recommend never using `|&` in Bash -- it's used here for demonstration.

- [Many of the obligatory redirection links](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Redirection)

Comment: +1. The only thing I'd add is that a pipe is a command separator, like semi-colon.

Comment: @ormaaj, there are a couple of section in the bash manual that will help you: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Commands and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Executing-Commands

Answer (score 8):

To add to ormaaj's answer:

The reason you need to specify redirection operators in the proper order is that they're evaluated from left to right.  Consider these command lists:

```
# print "hello" on stdout and "world" on stderr
{ echo hello; echo world >&2; }

# Redirect stdout to the file "out"
# Then redirect stderr to the file "err"
{ echo hello; echo world >&2; } > out 2> err

# Redirect stdout to the file "out"
# Then redirect stderr to the (already redirected) stdout
# Result: all output is stored in "out"
{ echo hello; echo world >&2; } > out 2>&1

# Redirect stderr to the current stdout
# Then redirect stdout to the file "out"
# Result: "world" is displayed, and "hello" is stored in "out"
{ echo hello; echo world >&2; } 2>&1 > out
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer is by understanding file descriptors. Each process has a bunch of file descriptors: entries to files that are opened. By default, number 0 is for stdin, number 1 is for stdout and number 2 is for stderr.

The i/o redirectors > and < by default connect to their most reasonable file descriptors, stout and stdin. If you re-route stdout to a file (as with `foo > bar`), on starting process 'foo', the file 'bar' is opened for writing and hooked on file descriptor number 1. If you want only stderr in 'bar', you'd use `foo 2> bar` which opens file bar and hooks it to the stderr.

Now the i/o redirector '2>&1'. I normally read that as 'put file descriptor 2 to the same as file descriptor 1. While reading the commandline from left to right, you can do the next: `foo 1>bar 2>&1 1>/dev/tty`. With this, file descriptor 1 is set to the file 'bar', file descriptor 2 is set to the same as 1 (hence 'bar') and after that, file descriptor 1 is set to /dev/tty. The runnning `foo` is sending its output to /dev/tty and it stderr to the file 'bar'.

Now the pipeline comes in: this does not alter the file descriptors, however, it will connect them between the processes: stdout of the left process ot stdin of the next. Stderr is passed on. Hence, if you like the pipeline to work on stderr only, you use `foo 2| bar`, which connects stderr of `foo` to stdin of `bar`. (I'm not sure what happens with the stdout of `foo`.)

With the above, if you use `foo 2>&1 | bar`, since stderr of `foo` is re-routed to stdout of `foo`, both stdout and stderr of `foo` arrive at the stdin of `bar`.